# return a dictionary with a number of instances for each character

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This function takes two character strings corresponding to two words and returns
True if and only if one is anagram of the other, that is, if the words are constituted by the
same letters, ignoring differences between uppercase and lowercase and the order between
characters.

```
>>> eh_anagrama(’caso’, ’SaCo’)
True
>>> eh_anagrama(’caso’, ’casos’)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but log-linear approach:

```
def eh_anagrama(s1, s2):
    return sorted(s1.lower()) == sorted(s2.lower())
```

Better linear approach, using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

def eh_anagrama(s1, s2):
    return Counter(s1.lower()) == Counter(s2.lower())
```

The benefits of this will probaby only be reaped for very long strings, as the sorting is heavily C-optimized.

Answer (score 0):

How about this with result and char counting in dict.

##### code

```
def anagram(s1, s2):
    ana = sorted(s1.lower()) == sorted(s2.lower())
    
    d1 = {}
    d2 = {}
    for x in set(s1):  # Get unique char
        d1.update({x: s1.count(x)})  # Count each char
    for x in set(s2):
        d2.update({x: s2.count(x)})

    return {'anagram': ana, s1: d1, s2: d2}


s1 = 'caso'
s2 = 'SaCo'
res1 = anagram(s1, s2)
print(res1)

s1 = 'caso'
s2 = 'casos'
res2 = anagram(s1, s2)
print(res2)
```

##### Output:

```
{'anagram': True, 'caso': {'o': 1, 's': 1, 'c': 1, 'a': 1}, 'SaCo': {'o': 1, 'C': 1, 'a': 1, 'S': 1}}
{'anagram': False, 'caso': {'o': 1, 's': 1, 'c': 1, 'a': 1}, 'casos': {'o': 1, 's': 2, 'c': 1, 'a': 1}}
```